# How to draw both object on the same window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, pyqt5, paintevent

Prologue: Both of the object represented below are on the same window.

I am having problem with the  not updating 
I am having a problem related to `self.setGeometry(x,y,w,h)` function. So what I want to achieve is multiple rect, rendered in parallel, which each has a line protruding out of their rectangle when clicked. (Creating a connector though that is not the point of this topic).

In this case, I have rect `A` and rect `B` rendering together. Rect `A` has a line protruding out to the position of the mouse.

```py
(obj A)           (obj B)
 ____              ____
|    |            |    |
|  \ |            |    |
 ---\              ----
     \
     (Mouse)
```

An example code of what am I trying to achieve.

```py
# File: connectors.py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class Connector(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, rect: List[int]):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.rect = rect
        self.clicked = False

        self.begin = QPoint(rect[0], rect[1])
        self.end = QPoint(0,0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setPen(Qt.red)
        qp.drawRect(*self.rect)

        if self.clicked:
            qp = QPainter()
            qp.begin(self)
            qp.setPen(Qt.red)
            qp.drawLine(self.begin, self.end)
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == 1:
            self.clicked = True
            self.end = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.clicked:
            self.end = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == 1:
            self.clicked = False
            self.end = event.pos()

# File: main.py
scene = QGraphicsScene()
scene.addWidget( Connector((400, 400, 100, 100)) )
scene.addWidget( Connector((400, 600, 100, 100)) )
```

But what I am ending up is PyQt showing the top-most object onto the screen thus only showing one object, **BUT** I also tried to minimize the geometry leading the protruding line, when clicked, cutting off on the border.

Comment: Mmm, could you explain yourself better, I don't understand your problem. What is your main objective? Maybe you are using the wrong tools.

Comment: So I am using PyQt5 to render my desktop app. A visually rich one. My objective is so I can render both rectangle on the same window. And also render the line from the position of the rectangle to the position of the mouse when the mouse is clicked.

Comment: mmm, okay, I see that there are 2 rectangles and therefore 2 lines then assuming they are rendered in the same window, which of the lines should be moved when the mouse is moved?

Comment: For technical reasons, both of the line from each `Connector` follows the position of the mouse when clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation:

In your case it has 2 widgets where you draw the rectangles where one is on top of another so you will only see one of them: the one above.

#### Solution:

Qt GraphicsView Framework (QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsXItem, etc.) works differently and painting is not used directly since they offer basic items that implement all the functionalities so in this case you must use QGraphicsRectItem with QGraphicsLineItem and modify it with the information of the QGraphicsView.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsLineItem,
    QGraphicsRectItem,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
)


class RectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, rect, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setRect(QRectF(*rect))
        self.setPen(Qt.red)
        self._line_item = QGraphicsLineItem(self)
        self.line_item.setPen(Qt.red)
        l = self.line_item.line()
        l.setP1(self.rect().topLeft())
        l.setP2(self.rect().topLeft())
        self.line_item.setLine(l)
        self.line_item.hide()

    @property
    def line_item(self):
        return self._line_item

    def move_line_to(self, sp):
        lp = self.mapFromScene(sp)
        l = self.line_item.line()
        l.setP2(lp)
        self.line_item.setLine(l)


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene())

        self.scene().addItem(RectItem((400, 400, 100, 100)))
        self.scene().addItem(RectItem((400, 600, 100, 100)))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        vp = event.pos()
        sp = self.mapToScene(vp)
        self.move_lines(sp)
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        vp = event.pos()
        sp = self.mapToScene(vp)
        self.move_lines(sp)
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        for item in self.items():
            if isinstance(item, RectItem):
                item.line_item.hide()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def move_lines(self, sp):
        for item in self.items():
            if isinstance(item, RectItem):
                item.line_item.show()
                item.move_line_to(sp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = GraphicsView()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do you know any good website tutorial for PyQt5 like RealPython for Python? C++ is ok.